# Oracle strange SUM behaviour

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two queries, which to my understanding should deliver the same result but they do not. Clearly I'm missing here some important point, which I hope you can help me out with.

1. Query (I assume this is the wrong one):

   ```
     SELECT SUM(a.amount) AS A_SUM ---10 727.470
     FROM billdetail a
     INNER JOIN bill c
       ON (a.bill_id = c.bill_id)
     INNER JOIN dates d
       ON (c.date_id = d.date_id)
     WHERE d.year                = '2014'
       AND c.status        <> 'D'
       AND a.status        <> 'D';
   ```
2. Query:

   ```
   SELECT SUM(C_SUM) ---10 754.279
   FROM
     (
     SELECT SUM(a.amount) AS C_SUM
     FROM billdetail a
     INNER JOIN bill c
       ON (a.bill_id = c.bill_id)
     INNER JOIN dates d
       ON (c.date_id = d.date_id)
     WHERE d.year                = '2014'
       AND c.status        <> 'D'
       AND a.status        <> 'D'
     GROUP BY c.bill_id
     );
   ```

As you can see, query 1 gives me 10 727.470 where query 2 gives me 10 754.279, so 27 less.

Can you explain me why this is? I thought I do here the same with both: select only the bills from 2014 and then from there on grab all billdetails of them and sum up the amounts. But clearly I have here some understanding problem I hope you can help me with.

Comment: Are you sure no id shows up twice in any of the tables?

Comment: You are missing the group by in the first query.

Comment: @ jarlh: well, of course for example bill no 100 has two entries in the billdetails table, because several items were ordered, it is 1:n

Comment: @Coder of Code: but why is that? I thought you only need group by with aggregate functions if you use columns in the select list to which you do not want to apply an aggregate function. Here I'm not interested in sums by bill_id. I only want to know the overall sum for those cases.

Comment: At first glance it should give same results. Are u sure that before second select there were no inserts?

Comment: another idea: what type is a.amount? it may be a float rounding error

Comment: I too think the queries should give the same result. It should make no difference at all if I sum all records at once or build subtotals first and then add these together.

Comment: Hi! Please Check your data again. Can you create a simple Test-Case with some CREATE TABLE - Statements and some INSERTS so we can reproduce the bug? Because on first sight it should behave the same

Comment: @cypherabe: Great thinking! That could be the culprit.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner But this should only happen if the table has some million rows and very small values... and WHO THE HELL saves monetary amounts as float ???

Comment: @Falco: Well, we are looking for the "impossible answer" :-) Looking at the queries, we all agree they must result in the same sum, but they don't. But I agree, it doesn't seem likely that there are that many rounding errors.

Comment: The data type of amount is NUMBER(27,8). And yes, there are no inserts happening between those two queries.

Comment: Is this the problem? NUMBER(27,8)? btw fyi: amount has this data type because the table itself is directly sourced from another system, and there it has this data type, so I take the same.

Comment: ah, and one more input: both bill and billdetail hold several 100 mio rows.

Comment: You could have a corrupt index or block corruption on the bill or billdetail table which could potentially cause this issue.

Comment: Did you try to find the difference in the data by looking at the raw, i.e. not summed up, records? And if there are too many, then first narrow down the difference by applying more filters. That could be breaking data up into months, then weeks, until you can compare it manually. Divide and conquer ... :-)

Comment: @Coder; doesn't matter, he's taking the sum of all records in both cases. That is records, that match the WHERE clause which is the same for both.

Comment: Does table `billdetail` have records where `bill_id` is NULL, but where column `amount` has any value (other than NULL) ?

Comment: Can you re-run both queries, in the same order, and show they have the same results ?

Comment: I'm trying to break down the data set. Tried with April of 2014, but there I get the same for both. I try now other months. No, bill_id is not nullable in both tables

Comment: @BateTech Rebuilding indexes could be a valid idea. If you are operating on NUMBER in Oracle, rounding should never be an issue with addition, since the all have the same precision. So I think a corrupt Index could be the culprit...

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  You can use that to research if there are any known Oracle bugs for your current version.  Practically every DMBS (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.) has had bugs at some point that were fixed and have to do with incorrect results being returned in certain isolated cases (when using certain joins, partitioned tables, prefetching, compression, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You may be hitting "Bug 4604970  Wrong results with 'hash group by' aggregation enabled".  You can avoid that bug by running `alter session set "_gby_hash_aggregation_enabled"=false;`.  Here's a simple test case for the bug, that sadly still exists after all these years.

```
SQL> select stddev(test), count(distinct test) from
  2  (
  3      select 7/9 test from dual
  4      union all
  5      select 7/9 test from dual
  6  );
select stddev(test), count(distinct test) from
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01428: argument '-.00000000000000000000000000000000000001' is out of range


SQL> alter session set "_gby_hash_aggregation_enabled"=false;

Session altered.

SQL> select stddev(test), count(distinct test) from
  2  (
  3      select 7/9 test from dual
  4      union all
  5      select 7/9 test from dual
  6  );

STDDEV(TEST) COUNT(DISTINCTTEST)
------------ -------------------
           0                   1
```

Comment: that could be it.... o_O that is one scary bug, if you are using aggregates for financial records this can really lead to a big mess